# Odoo searching partner using vat number

Tags: odoo-10

Hi guys i was using Odoo 10, Is there a way to search partner using vat number instead of partner name when creating invoice?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is there any vat number field in account.invoice?

Comment: No there is no vat number field...

Comment: then put vat number field in invoice and add it in search view

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question... what i want is when i create sales to invoice there is a customer field which let's you search customer/ partner using name of the partner then it automatically populate other fields depending on then customer property, so instead of searching by name i want to search the customer using partners vat number... I found a module (https://github.com/adhoc-dev/odoo-addons/tree/8.0/partner_search_by_vat) but it only works for odoo v8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There is a way to do that. You can try my solution

1. Add a context in the `partner` field to set, that you want to search by *vat*. Here you can use `xpath`.

```py
context="{'search_by_vat': True}"
```

2. Overwrite the function `name_search` in `res.partner`:

```py
class Partner(models.Model):
_inherit = 'res.partner'

    @api.model
    def name_search(self, name='', args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100):
        if self._context.get('search_by_vat', False):
            if name:
                args = args If i Want to search in both name and vat what should i do?if args else []
                args.append(['vat', 'ilike', name])
                name = ''
        return super(Partner, self).name_search(name=name, args=args, operator=operator, limit=limit)
```

> If i Want to search in both name and vat what should i do?

You can use `['name', 'ilike', name] or ['vat', 'ilike', name]`

```py
class Partner(models.Model):
_inherit = 'res.partner'

    @api.model
    def name_search(self, name='', args=None, operator='ilike', limit=100):
        if self._context.get('search_by_vat', False):
            if name:
                args = args if args else []
                args.extend(['|', ['name', 'ilike', name], ['vat', 'ilike', name]])
                name = ''
        return super(Partner, self).name_search(name=name, args=args, operator=operator, limit=limit)
```

Comment: Yes, you should create a custom module.

Comment: Hi i tried it your way but it's not working... I removed the if statement since i want it to work all the time                                                                          Here is the error  [ NameError: global name 'Partner' is not defined ]

Comment: You must use the class name in your module. `Partner` is the class name in my module. You can read more about it hier: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712300/inheritance-in-openerp-odoo)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712300/inheritance-in-openerp-odoo]

Comment: The link doesn't work....  here is my class  [ class res_partner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner' ]      so should i use res_partner instead of Partner

Comment: exactly. try it... Again the usefully link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712300/inheritance-in-openerp-odoo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712300/inheritance-in-openerp-odoo)

Comment: I tried and the error goes away but still the functionality is not working... when i insert the vat number in the customer field it doesn't know the customer it asks me to create a new customer...

Comment: Hey sorry. I have checked the code. The `search_key` isn't store in `display_name`. It's stored in `name`. Can you please try my correction?

Comment: Hi i tried the changes but it's still doesn't work, please see the question to see the code...

Comment: HI, i saw your code. Indentation is false. Please look my code again. Don't forget to restart the server and update the module again. If you didn't set `context` in your view, you must take the `if` out `if self._context.get('search_by_vat', False):`

Comment: Hey, sorry i mistakenly screwed up the indentation when i posted the code so  the indentation is true here... and i already took out the if statement on the context and i restarted the server every time i update then module but still it's not working (check the question for the new code)

Comment: i don't know. Somewhere is wrong. It works now on my env. Did't you wrote a module before?

Comment: Finally it works... there was a database error and i tried in a fresh install of odoo and it works... Thank you Very much

Comment: If i Want to search in both name and vat what should i do?

Comment: Then you should remove this line `name = ''`

Comment: Ah right. That's `AND` not `OR`. You can use `['|', ['name', 'ilike', name], ['vat', 'ilike', name]]`

Comment: Still not working... can u update the answer including the new code... thanks

Comment: I am getting a this error... type error unhashable type list... have u tried the code in ur end...

Comment: sorry, i missed a `]` in the end of the domain

Comment: I already added  ] at the end of the domain... but the error is still there

Comment: For the second code i used `extend` instead `append`. Did you added it too?